# Issue with displaying selected value in Autocomplete component

Tags: javascript, material-ui, autocomplete, formik

I'm facing an issue while using the Autocomplete component in my application. I have an Autocomplete field where a pre-defined value should be displayed, but I also want to allow the user to select a different option. However, when I select a different option and click outside the component, it doesn't display the selected value correctly.

Here is the relevant code:

```js
// Imports and declarations omitted for brevity

const selectedAccount = {
  codconta: editCaixa?.codconta || "",
};

<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={{
    codservico: editCaixa?.codservico || "",
    datalancamento: editCaixa?.datalancamento || "",
    codconta: editCaixa.codconta || "",
    menumonico: editCaixa?.menumonico || "",
    descrconta: editCaixa?.descrconta || "",
    historico: editCaixa?.historico || "",
    valorlancamento: editCaixa?.valorlancamento || "",
    numcheque: editCaixa?.numcheque || "",
  }}
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    handleSubmitForm(values);
  }}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
>
  <Autocomplete
    id="codconta"
    options={filtroConta.map((option) => ({
      codconta: option.codconta,
      menumonico: option.menumonico,
      descrconta: option.descrconta,
      label: `${option.codconta} - ${option.menumonico} - ${option.descrconta}`,
    }))}
    value={selectedAccount}
    onChange={(e, value) => {
      console.log(value);
      setFieldValue(
        "codconta",
        value !== null ? value.codconta : initialValues.codconta
      );
    }}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.codconta}`}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextfieldWrapper
        label="Account"
        name="codconta"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        touched={touched.codconta}
        errors={errors.codconta}
        {...params}
      />
    )}
  />
</Formik>
```

The problem is that when I select a different option and click outside the component, the selected value is not displayed correctly in the field. Instead, it appears as undefined. However, if I check the values in the console, I can see that the selected option is being saved correctly in the API.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue and display the selected value correctly in the Autocomplete field?